How Can We Develop a Methodology to Measure Bitcoin’s Actual Value Creation?
I seeks a clear and actionable methodology to measure Bitcoin’s unique value creation compared to other cryptocurrencies, stablecoins, and traditional financial systems. Specifically, they are asking:

How can we reliably differentiate Bitcoin-specific value creation (e.g., from decentralization, censorship resistance) from general blockchain-based financial innovations?

What measurable metrics or frameworks can demonstrate how Bitcoin’s decentralization translates into actual economic value, rather than simply describing potential benefits?

How can Bitcoin’s value creation be compared to technology companies like Google, Tesla, or Amazon, whose market cap reflects their contribution to increasing the economy’s productive potential?


Existing ideas in the conversation include analyzing remittance cost savings, transaction efficiency (e.g., Lightning Network), and financial inclusion through wallet adoption. However, these metrics often describe potential benefits rather than provide a definitive way to measure actual value creation.
